# Airflow TriggerDagRunOperator Changes

Tags: airflow

The Apache Airflow project has seemingly forced the TriggerDagRunOperator `conf` to allow JSON only. This is different than how it was previously where I was allowed to pass class instances without any special handling.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.py#L94

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/api/common/experimental/trigger_dag.py#L65

These are the 2 snippets that enforce this.

Is anyone facing this issue as well? If so, how are you working around this limitation?

I'm currently bypassing this issue by creating a custom operator based on the operator before these changes.

Comment: The said line in `TriggerDagRunOperator` was changed way back in [May 2018](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blame/master/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.py#L94). While in any early-stage (recently came out of *incubating* phase) like `Airflow`, such breaking changes are common, but in this case it indeed appears as though this change went [unnoticed](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/CHANGELOG.txt#L75) (probably even unintended) because [the commit](https://github.com/apache/airflow/commit/089c996fbd9ecb0014dbefedff232e8699ce6283) in question was meant to solve something else